# How can I subscribe to Data from router config on NavigationEnd?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Currently**: I am subscribing to `router.events` to get *data* from `{path: '', component: HomeComponent, data:{header:true}},` router config

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(event => {
          console.log(this.route.firstChild.data.value.header); //returns the correct data BUT also a tpye error
      });
  }
```

that works. it will go fetch the correct data from the router config (`this.route.firstChild.data.value.header`) BUT it has the following error.

`ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(29,52): error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Observable<Data>'.`

I think i need to subscribe to the data some how because it is an observables. But my attempts are not working

Comment: Are you not after subscribing on the data object. `this.route.firstChild.data.subscribe(value =>{console.log(value.header);});`

Answer (score 0):

You could `take` a value from the data property like this:

Example:

```
const routeData$ = this.route.firstChild.data.take(1);

this.router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd).switchMap(() => routeData$).subscribe((data) => // data )
```